# Get system uptime with better precision then seconds

Tags: clock, uptime

My system is running Linux for embedded.
At the moment I didn't sync the system clock or gave the user an option to do it but it's going to change.

Different parts in my application are using timestamps, I want to use different clock then the system clock for this timestamps so they will not get affected when the system time is change by ntp/user.
I know that the system has the uptime value so it's keeping track on a different clock beside the system clock, but the precision of the uptime is too low (seconds)...

Is there a way to get the uptime with better precision (milliseconds)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`/proc/uptime` gives the uptime in hundredths of a second.

If you want more precise values, you could write a kernel module based on [the `/proc/uptime` implementation](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/fs/proc/uptime.c).

Comment: Thank you.
What about the performance, reading system time comparing reading thru kernel module that uses /proc/uptime?

Comment: Ultimately the performance would be similar, you’re calling into the kernel in both cases. This *could* be hosted in the vDSO if performance was really important.

Comment: Is this a kernel call, or does it use the memory mapped kernel data trick (edit: is that the vDSO that you mentioned).

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor reading from `/proc` always involves kernel calls (`read` & co.). The vDSO can use the memory-mapped kernel data trick; but that involves adding a vDSO call.

Comment: I just want to make sure that I didn't missed anything.
I've created a simple kernel module with IOCTL cmd.
I've used the "u64 ktime_get_ns(void)" I found here:
https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/core-api/timekeeping.html

My system doesn't have any battery so i think it's okay to use this function.
Then I simply copied the value to the user space.

I can see that it's working, when the system is up both system time and my module time return the same time (1970...), after setting the time to the current time the system time is set to a new time and my module keeps his state.

Comment: I've changed the implementation. I read the time similar to the /proc/uptime implementation, with ktime_get_boottime_ts64. Reading with u64 ktime_get_ns return the right result but because the return value is in nano sec it will wraparound after 500+ years so it's good to be prepared : )

Comment: Nice, let me know when you have an embedded system which can stay up without rebooting for 500 years ;-).